# Variable vs Single or 2-Stage Furnace -- Noise Issue

Tags: furnace

Will a much costlier variable speed be significantly quieter than a single or 2-stage furnace in a TV room where I'm adding a cold air return-- also adding central air to entire house.

Comment: Not enough information. Significantly is hard to quantify; it will be more energy efficient but that might not matter if every room is occupied at the same time. Running the fan at a lower speed lowers the 'air noise', but moves less air as well. Very hard to establish an answer.

Comment: This is going to *massively* depend on your duct static pressures -- getting those measured is the first step to taming air-handler noise in your house.  (Static pressure, BTW, is how HVAC folks measure how much "oomph" is needed to push air through your ducts; the less static pressure drop there is in the ductwork, the more efficiently air flows through it, allowing your furnace blower to rest easy at night.)